# PHP install complete on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7, 404.3 error by handler FASTCGI installed?

Tags: php, iis-7, installation, windows-server-2008, fastcgi

I know theres a lot of info on installing PHP on Server 2008....everything seems to be installed correctly.  I'm getting a 404.3 error...which is usually a result of a non-existant handler, but FASTCGI seems to be functioning, theres a instance of php-cgi.exe loaded into the FastCGI settings with max instances set at 5 and max requests at 10000, and under handler mappings, the *.php request path is pointing at FastCgiModule and has the correct path for the executable.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for anyone else thats tried EVERYTHING like I did and runs across this....remember that your handlers for your sites already established dont naturally inherit that of your base configuration (of course not, why would microsoft do something that intelligent natively).  Bottom line, my handlers were established for IIS but then I had to go in and establish them for each of my individual sites.  Go figure.